# Protecting my REST requests in Android?

Tags: android, authentication, rest

I have a server side script which gets some data that my application uses. Naturally, I don't want anyone else access the data aside from my app. I've heard it's possible to see which url's the device connects when using a certain software. How can I prevent these programs seeing the url's I'm calling to? Or is there a better way of securing the requests?

Only thing I can think of is using a password key in the url (and check if it matches on the server side):

```
http://example.com/getdata?key=897ihrduiuyqewudiew&get=something
```

but that probably isn't enough for a secure authentication. And the sniffer programs could still get that url. Any simple way of doing this more securely?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use HTTPS. This way, only the server to which you connect to can be known by the sniffer.

There are other methods that use complex challenging to have a unique key only valid for a short period of time / a single request, like WSSE (see this article http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/12/17/dive.html )

Comment: HTTPS is probably what could do it for me, but I have no idea how to implement it both on server and Android side. I have searched about it before and couldn't find an example I could understand.

Comment: you don't have anything to do on the android side. On the server side you need a certificate, avoid rapidssl since there are issues with android 2.2. There are tons on tutorials on how to include an ssl certificate on many web server

Comment: Okay. So this would be good on my use case (no sensitive information storeed on the server, just to prevent abuse), and those sniffing programs only get the `https://example.com/` part of my request and not `https://example.com/get?key=1234567`?

Answer (score 0):

There is very little you can do in order to protect the server requests. Someone will always be able to see the URLs your application hits and using a password in the query string won't help. In order to secure your application you need to use HTTPS and some form of authentication. The user will need to provide a username and password in order to connect.

Comment: That wouldn't be very good solution in my case because there's no possibility in user registration in the web version of the app. That would just confuse the users.

Comment: I am afraid there is no other way. There is no way to distinguish your application from another client that can't be fooled by a sniffer. A "naive" solution would be to encrypt the data and decrypt them in your Android client. You would need a symmetric key that has to be hardcoded in your application. A determined user could still find his way and reveal the key. For some cases it may be OK though.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you should implement **mutual authentication**. Basically, you have certificates on both your client and server. When a request is made to the server, the server verifies that request is signed by a known client.

So, even if a sniffer knows the url and attempts to issue the same request to the server, it would be *rejected* since it is *not signed by a known client*. I am quite new to this as well, but that is the general concept. This blog has the basic steps.

- http://blog.callistaenterprise.se/2011/11/24/creating-self-signed-certificates-for-use-on-android/
- http://blog.callistaenterprise.se/2011/11/24/android-tlsssl-mutual-authentication/